# Поиск в ListView.builder по названию элемента из JSON во Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Я делаю  обычный поиск по названию из JSON. Проблема в том, что вроде все работает (по крайне мере, у меня нет  ошибок в стэктрэйсе), но я просто не могу понять, почему не работает поиск (принтом вывожу, отрабатывает весь виджет _serachBar, но поиск по названию не начинается). Я сначала решил, что нужно использовать Future внутри виджета поиска, но это тоже не дало результатов. Может ли кто-нибудь указать мне, что именно происходит не так? Может, мне тоже нужно создать массив для добавления результатов поиска? Так как поиск элемента у меня завязан на алгоритме сортировки, то я не могу просто взять одну модель классам Routes и по ней проводить поиск:

Сейчас вся страница выглядит вот так:

```
class MarshrutesPage extends StatefulWidget {
          final int ttId;
        
          MarshrutesPage({this.ttId});
        
          @override
          _MarshrutesPageState createState() => _MarshrutesPageState();
        }
        
        class _MarshrutesPageState extends State<MarshrutesPage> {
          Box<RouteWithStops> favoriteRoutesBox;
          TransportService service = getIt<TransportService>();
        
         
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            favoriteRoutesBox = Hive.box(favoritesBox);
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'favorite');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                elevation: 0.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                title: Text(
                  'Название',
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ),
              body: FutureBuilder(
                  future: service.getMarshrutWithStops(widget.ttId),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                    List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
                    print(routes?.toString());
                    return (routes == null)
                        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                        : ValueListenableBuilder(
                            valueListenable: favoriteRoutesBox.listenable(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: routes.length + 1,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return index == 0
                                      ? _searchBar(routes)
                                      : _listItem(index - 1, routes);
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          );
                  }),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.message,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                       
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await launch("mailto: @gmail.com");
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey), onPressed: () {}),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.grey),
                          onPressed: () {}),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.map, color: Colors.grey), onPressed: () {}),
                    ]),
              ),
            );
          }
        
          Widget getIcon(int index) {
            if (favoriteRoutesBox.containsKey(index)) {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red);
            }
            return Icon(Icons.favorite_border);
          }
        
          void onFavoritePress(int index, List<RouteWithStops> routes) {
            if (favoriteRoutesBox.containsKey(index)) {
              favoriteRoutesBox.delete(index);
              return;
            }
            favoriteRoutesBox.put(index, routes[index]);
          }
        
          _listItem(index, List<RouteWithStops> routes) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(routes[index].route.mrTitle),
              leading: Text(
                routes[index].route.mrNum,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: getIcon(index),
                onPressed: () => onFavoritePress(index, routes),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => StopsPage(
                              routeWithStops: routes[index],
                            )));
              },
            );
          }
        
          _searchBar(List<RouteWithStops> routes) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search',
                  hoverColor: Colors.green,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  text = text.toLowerCase();
                  setState(() {
                    routes = routes.where((element) {
                      var routesTitle = element.route.mrTitle.toLowerCase();
                      return routesTitle.contains(text);
                    }).toList();
                    print('test2');
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Все прекрасно отрисовывается: то есть все виджеты отрабатывают (_listItem и _serachBar), http-запросы срабатывают и алгоритм тоже срабатывает, но поиск почему-то не работает.

Сам алгоритм:

```
 Future<List<RouteWithStops>> getMarshrutWithStops(int ttId) async {
    if (routesbyTransportType.isEmpty) {
      await fetchTransportWithRoutes();
    }
    List<Routes> routes = routesbyTransportType[ttId].routes;
    List<ScheduleVariants> variants = [];

    variants.addAll(await api.fetchSchedule());

    List<RouteWithStops> routesWithStops = [];

    for (Routes route in routes) {
      final routeWithStops = RouteWithStops();

      routesWithStops.add(routeWithStops);
      routeWithStops.route = route;

      routeWithStops.variant =
          variants.where((variant) => variant.mrId == route.mrId).first;

  
    }
    return routesWithStops;
  }
```

Я также видел решение, где в initState помещают запрос и получается примерно вот такой код:

```
List<Post> posts = [];

initState(){
setState(){
getPosts.then(value)){
posts.addAll(value);
}
}
}
```

И дальше уже не нужно прописывать FutureBuilder в основном виджете, а просто использовать posts по всему древу виджетов, просто объявив его в самом верху, но у меня все приложение завязано на алгоритме и я пробовал такой способ, но ничего не отрабатывало.

Я идиот, я понял, в чем ошибка: я в _searchBar передаю `List<RouteWithStops> routes`, то есть когда я пытаюсь искать по названиям, мне просто выгружает полностью весь список, какой есть внутри этого массива данных, а самого поиска по названию не происходит. Но как это исправить? По сути я не должен передавать в этот виджет никаких массивов, но если я объявляю новый массив вверху всего древа виджетов, то либо приложение полностью крашнеться, либо опять не работает поиск. Проблема в том, что я жестко завязан на этом алгоритме.

Comment: Не могли бы вы минимальный пример на [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) выложить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решалась довольно просто, нужно было просто быть чуть внимательнее: в общем, нужно объявить наверху в самом древе виджетов два массива:

```
 List<RouteWithStops> _routes = [];
 List<RouteWithStops> _routesToDisplay = [];
```

Первый массив отвечает за все элементы списка, которые необходимо вывести под строкой поиска. Второй массив нужен, чтобы когда вы настроили поиск и ввели туда определенное название/значение, то оно не провисало в воздухе, а подгружало новое. Например, вы ищете название по автору: Толстой Л.Н. "Война и мир". Если вы оставите как есть, не добавляя второй массив, то у вас так и повиснет Толстой Л.Н. "Война и мир" до следующей перезагрузки. Так быть не должно.

Чтобы избежать этого надо сделать следующее:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    service.getMarshrutWithStops(widget.ttId).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _routes.addAll(value);
        _routesToDisplay = _routes;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

В пустой второй массив записываются данные из первого массива, таким образом поиск становится, так скажем, динамическим и теперь отображаются все книги автора и при стирании фамилии автора из поиска загружается остальной массив, а не висит только то, что было набрано в поиске.

В древе виджетов делаем все то же самое, что и у меня в вопросе, только с той разницей, что в _listItem мы передаем только index и ничего более, а чтобы загрузка происходила корректно нужно просто в главном виджете перед ListView.builder добавить загрузку, используя тернарные операторы:

```
 body:  (_routes == null) ? CircularProgressIndicator() : ValueListenableBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {  
        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _routesToDisplay.length + 1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return index == 0
                                ? _searchBar()
                                : _listItem(index-1);
                          },
                        );
```

**P.S** Тут не нужен ValueListenableBuilder, это я начал делать сохранение в БД выбранных элементов, для загрузки нужна только эта строчка:  `(_routes == null) ? CircularProgressIndicator() : ListView.builder`

Также в виджетах для отображения списка и поиска вместо `_routes` добавляем `_routesToDisplay` и получается вот так:

```
 _listItem(index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(_routesToDisplay[index].route.mrTitle),
      leading: Text(
        _routesToDisplay[index].route.mrNum,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 20),
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: getIcon(index),
        onPressed: () => onFavoritePress(index, _routes),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => StopsPage(
                      routeWithStops: _routes[index],
                    )));
      },
    );
  }

  _searchBar() {
    print('test1');
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Search',
          hoverColor: Colors.green,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
        onChanged: (text) {
          text = text.toLowerCase();
          setState(() {
            print('object');
            _routesToDisplay = _routes.where((element) {
              var routesTitle = element.route.mrTitle.toLowerCase();
              print(routesTitle);
              return routesTitle.contains(text);
            }).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Думаю полезно было бы использовать понятный паттерн MVP или Redux; Чтобы была возможность провести изолированный от UI тест